# Correct way to create Registry Key using C# installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, installation, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have created installer project in visual studio, Now my task is to add Registry Key of installer And i have done creating Registry key from installer like Right click on installer project -> view -> registry
it create Registry Key with provided Name but it add Default Name also in that

Name
(Default)

ABC

Data
(value not set)

c:....\

why (Default) is created i just want ABC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why (Default) is created i just want ABC

It's the [expected behavior](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080118-00/?p=23773) that you see the Name(default) in registry editor.

[image]

As I know, there's no registry key that doesn't have that line. Its value can be empty, but that line will always exists.

You can easily check this by creating a new key in `Registry Editor`, you'll see the default line there.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a key in the Registry using the below code. This example adds the value pair, "Name" and "Isabella", to the current user's registry, under the key "Names".

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;  
key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Names");  
key.SetValue("Name", "Isabella");  
key.Close();
```

Here is the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-create-a-key-in-the-registry